# Why any executable leaks memory?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

Even

```
int
main () {
  return 0;
}
```

leaks memory. Indeed, running valgrind[0] outputs

```
==21013== HEAP SUMMARY:
==21013==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==21013==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 72,704 bytes allocated
==21013== 
==21013== LEAK SUMMARY:
==21013==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21013==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21013==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21013==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==21013==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Why is it so? And how should I personally check for memory leaks if Valgrind is supposed to fail leak checks with c++?

[0], `echo "int main() { return 0; }"|c++ -x c++ - -o Main && valgrind ./Main`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Valgrind shows you, that everything is all right, nothing leaked:

```
definitely lost: 0 bytes
indirectly lost: 0 bytes
  possibly lost: 0 bytes
```